# Wordpress 3.2 - removed ability to select a page template in the page attributes when adding a new page?

Tags: pages, page-template, page-attributes

Maybe it's just the site I'm running but has the 3.2 update removed the ability to select a page template in the page attributes when adding a new page?

It's kinda essential unless anyone knows a way around it?

Comment: no. the page attributes and page template both options are in there places. check your screen options on the top right corner.

Comment: Page attributes is ticked but the box just doesn't have a templates drop down.

Comment: What Theme are you using? Does your current Theme *have* custom Page templates from which to choose?

Comment: I'm using the default theme, yes I've got some custom templates in there. They work perfectly fine on a 3.1 install.

Comment: Sounds like a personal problem. Does the Quick Edit show the templates dropdown normally too?

Comment: By "default theme", do you mean TwentyTen, TwentyEleven, or Default?

Comment: I had the same problem, but the Template option DOES appear on my quick edit screen. Thanks for your seemingly unintentional help otto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though it was a personal problem. A knew install solved the problem so it must've been clashing with some legacy data.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't leave any space after "template name" and full column.

Right

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About
*/
?>
```

Wrong

```
<?php
/*
Template Name : About
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here.

Try to activate the Twenty Eleven theme e reactivate your actual theme. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem creating the correct header in the style.css of my custom theme

```
/*
Theme Name:
Theme URI:
Description:
Author:
Author URI:
*/
```

Comment: Why would creating a header in your stylesheet effect whether or not theme templates are available? Are you sure you are addressing the _question_ with this answer?